# Answer to an algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> The parabola $y=x^2-3bx-5$, in the $x-y$ plane, has its vertex at
> $(3,4)$. What is the value of $b$?

I can't answer it. There is no value for $b$ such that, when multiplied by 3, gives 5 and also makes the equation equal 4 when $x$ is 3 (to get the vertex). I'm pretty stumped all around. The problem is from a private SAT prep company. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

What does "vertex" mean for a parabola? In general,
$$
y=a(x-h)^2+k\tag{1}
$$
has the vertex $(h,k)$.

Now write the equation of your parabola in the form of (1) by [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

Alternatively, your parabola can be written as
$$
y=a(x-3)^2+4\tag{2}
$$
for some real number $a$. Expand (2) and compare it with your equation to find $b$.

---

<sup>Following the hint above, you will find that the number $b$ that satisfies the assumptions does not exist.</sup>

Comment: So to complete the square,

Comment: So to complete the square, $$y=x^2-3bx-5$$ 
$$x^2-3bx   =5$$
$$x^2-\frac{3b}{2}x+(\frac{3b}{2})^2=5+(\frac{3b}{2})^2$$
$$(x-\frac{3b}{2})^2=5+(\frac{3b}{2})^2$$
Is that correct? I don't see where that gets me.

Comment: You are almost done. But you should not write $x^2-3bx=5$. Instead, you calculation tells you that $y=(x-\frac{3b}{2})^2-5-(\frac{3b}{2})^2$. On the other hand, you know that the vertex is given by $(3,4)$ and the vertex for $y=a(x-h)^2+k$ is $(h,k)$.// Nevertheless, it is very likely that you copied the problem wrong since no such $b$ exists.

Comment: @michaelrr: can you double check your original problem? It must be that you have a wrong problem from the author.

Comment: Yes, it definitely says, "vertex (3,4) and equation $y = x^2 - 3bx -5$. I am sorry to have wasted your time with a misprint. Thanks for your careful attention. That seems to be more than the textbook writers will willing to offer.

Comment: @michaelrr: do you have a screenshot for that? // well, the principle to solve the problem is unchanged. The answer to the problem as stated would be simply "$b$ does not exist".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any value of $b$ for which it can be the vertex.

Proof:

$4=9-9b-5$ (Vertex lies on the parabola)

$\implies b=0$

But the slope of tangent at the vertex should be zero,
that is $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ at the vertex.

$\implies 2x-3b=0$ at $x=3$

$\implies b=2$ so there isn't any value of $b$ which satisfies that.

Comment: That does it. I am sorry for apparently wasting your time on a misprint or careless mistake on the textbook writer's part. I really appreciate all the work you put into it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is easiest to see whether or not there is a solution to this problem using graphing.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x7cwulidgt

Hint: manipulate the value of $b$ to convince yourself of whether or not there is some value of $b$ for which the parabola with the general equation $y=x^2+3bx-5$ can have a vertex of $P(3,4)$.

Comment: But there is no value of b for which the vertex is (3,4)? The only way the line goes through 3,4 at all is when *b* is zero. Is it possible that the question is a mistake on the author's part?

Comment: You are correct: there is no value for $b$ for which the vertex is $P(3,4)$. The vertex will always lie somewhere on the parabola $y=-x^2-5$, which the point $P(3,4)$ is not on. I would reread the question, but if the problem is as you've presented it above, there is no value of $b$ for which the parabola $y=x^2-3bx-5$ will have a vertex of $P(3,4)$

Comment: They likely meant $y=-x^2-3bx-5$ as this does have a vertex of $P(3,4)$ for some value of $b$. If you want to complete this problem for practice, I recommend using that parabola instead.